# Spring Hibernate 4 support

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am using Hibernate 4 CR1. My application was previously using Spring hibernate support (for version 3).

I have not been able to find any information about this - is there any indication as to when (or which version) Spring will provide support for Hibernate 4?

Comment: 4.0 is only about to be released. I am curious: what are the features in 4.x, which are essential for your project?

Answer (score 6):

> UPDATE: [Spring Framework 3.1 goes GA](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/12/13/spring-framework-3-1-goes-ga/)

You need to upgrade to Spring 3.1.0.RC1 released today:

[Spring 3.1.0.RC1 Released](http://www.springsource.org/node/3279):

> Support for Hibernate 4.0 (up to date with 4.0 CR4)

Answer (score 0):

As per comment of one of the guys is is involved in the spring project it seems that they started working on hibernate 4 support:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115682-Migrating-application-context-configuration-to-Spring-3.1-and-Hibernate-4.0&p=382864#post382864