# JPA 2.0 & Hibernate 4.0.1 & Spring 3.1.1 Compatibility

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Spring 3.1.1 in my application.
I have integrated JPA and Hibernate 4.0.1 into it.

My entityManagerFactory and few more beans are not getting instantiated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildLifecycleControledServiceRegistry(Ejb3Configuration.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:903)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:117)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:116)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/User-1/MuleStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/eigSourceCode/appendContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildLifecycleControledServiceRegistry(Ejb3Configuration.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:903)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 38 more
```

I am not supposed to use Maven, so i am adding jars directly to class path.

The Jars inside class path are:

[image: Referenced Libraries]

[image: Spring Jars inside mule studio]

My persistance.xml is inside META-INF, and the code inside is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="03offileLogger">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.comviva.mfs.eig.persistance.jpa.entities.TransactionLog</class>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The `appendContext.xml` is my application Context file used for configuring spring beans which contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <!-- scans the classpath for annotated components (including @Repostory 
        and @Service that will be auto-registered as Spring beans -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.comviva.mfs.eig.logging.dataAccess, com.comviva.mfs.eig.logging.service" />

    <!-- methods or classes needing to run in a complete transaction will be 
        annotated with Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eigDB" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="03offileLogger" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The errors pasted above are cut to fit the size,
But after each error it is saying

```
Invocation of init method failed;
 Initialization of bean failed;
```

I read it somewhere that there is some version conflict, so the entityManagerFactory is not being instantiated.

**Update:**
The code below shows my entity (only one table).

```
package com.comviva.mfs.eig.persistance.jpa.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


/**
 * The persistent class for the transaction_logs database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="transaction_logs")
public class TransactionLog implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="TRANSACTION_ID")
    private Long transaction_id; 

    @Column(name="INTERFACE_ID")
    private String interfaceId;

    @Column(name="FROM_ACCOUNT")
    private String from_account;


    @Column(name="SERVICE_TYPE")
    private String serviceType;

    @Column(name = "MSISDN")
    private String msisdn;


    @Column(name="TRANSACTION_TIME")
    private Timestamp transactionTime;


    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_DATE")
    private Timestamp transactionDate;


    @Column(name="FROM_ACCOUNT_TYPE")
    private Integer fromAccountType;


    @Column(name="TRANSMISSION_DATE_TIME")
    private Timestamp transmissionDateTime;


    @Column(name="INTERFACE_TXN_ID")
    private Long interfaceTxnId;

    @Column(name="AVILABLE_BALANCE")
    private Double avilableBalance;

    @Column(name="TOTAL_BALANCE")
    private Double totalBalance;

    @Column(name="TXN_STATUS")
    private String txnStatus;

    @Column(name="MESSAGE")
    private String message;

    public TransactionLog() {
    }

    public Long getTransaction_id() {
        return transaction_id;
    }

    public void setTransaction_id(Long transaction_id) {
        this.transaction_id = transaction_id;
    }

    public String getInterfaceId() {
        return interfaceId;
    }

    public void setInterfaceId(String interfaceId) {
        this.interfaceId = interfaceId;
    }

    public String getFrom_account() {
        return from_account;
    }

    public void setFrom_account(String from_account) {
        this.from_account = from_account;
    }

    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }

    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    public String getMsisdn() {
        return msisdn;
    }

    public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
    }

    public Timestamp getTransactionTime() {
        return transactionTime;
    }

    public void setTransactionTime(Timestamp transactionTime) {
        this.transactionTime = transactionTime;
    }

    public Timestamp getTransactionDate() {
        return transactionDate;
    }

    public void setTransactionDate(Timestamp transactionDate) {
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    }

    public Integer getFromAccountType() {
        return fromAccountType;
    }

    public void setFromAccountType(Integer fromAccountType) {
        this.fromAccountType = fromAccountType;
    }

    public Timestamp getTransmissionDateTime() {
        return transmissionDateTime;
    }

    public void setTransmissionDateTime(Timestamp transmissionDateTime) {
        this.transmissionDateTime = transmissionDateTime;
    }

    public Long getInterfaceTxnId() {
        return interfaceTxnId;
    }

    public void setInterfaceTxnId(Long interfaceTxnId) {
        this.interfaceTxnId = interfaceTxnId;
    }

    public Double getAvilableBalance() {
        return avilableBalance;
    }

    public void setAvilableBalance(Double avilableBalance) {
        this.avilableBalance = avilableBalance;
    }

    public Double getTotalBalance() {
        return totalBalance;
    }

    public void setTotalBalance(Double totalBalance) {
        this.totalBalance = totalBalance;
    }

    public String getTxnStatus() {
        return txnStatus;
    }

    public void setTxnStatus(String txnStatus) {
        this.txnStatus = txnStatus;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


}
```

Please help me Resolve my Problem.

Comment: Post the _relevant_ parts of the stacktrace. If you don't know what is relevant, post _all_ of it.

Comment: I have posted the entire stack trace error as you said.
Please help me find out the solution.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366143/spring-hibernate-4-support

Comment: @RC. - They are talking about Spring 3.0 and hibernate 4.0 which was not final.
I am using all latest jars, besides i dint find any content regarding creation of entity manager factory (session factory instead as they are not using JPA).

Comment: related (but no answer at all): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553202/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-cfg-environment-verifyproperties

Comment: Check whether there are multiple classess (version) in the class path (in Eclipse use Ctr+Shit+T). If there are remove the incorrect version. If there is only one, verify the method signature of the following method org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map)           (i.e. verify if the method takes the Map. If there is no such method, it could mean you are using a wrong version of Hibernate.)

Comment: The problem is not org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map)

The problem is above that which cannot instantiate entityManagerFactory.

When even a bean instance is not getting created if we used hibernate 4.0 we get this error.
If we resolve bean instantiation problem, the below problem of "verifyProperties"gets automatically resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties" means you do have a different version of class `org.hibernate.cfg.Environment`

Your error log says you are using mule. Mule comes with its own hibernate jar. Please check the lib directory of mule to confirm that you don't have a conflicting hibernate jars.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Entities, relationships defined? Can you take  thise out and let just EntityManager initialize?

The reason is simple, I think I saw this kind of errors when there was a problem with my Entities and relations

Comment: Yes I have one entity which is defined..
Will edit my question see if you can find out what is the actual problem.

Comment: I am not getting the entity manager , 
i have edited the question.
Please help me, issue is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Hibernate jars present in the Mule server,
i.e:location sample: `C:\dev\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.2.ee_4.1.0.201410031231\mule\lib\opt`.

Reason: If you have developed your app with specific version of Hibernate, then you need to have the same version in the mule server because while you running your app in the mule server it uses its own copy of it.